# CocoaDialog standard-dropdown confusion

Tags: bash

I have two, possibly related, issues. Firstly, my return value is apparently not being set to the result variable. And secondly, the --button1 flag and its associated text are actually showing up in the --items list. I've tried every scenario of "$result" == "#" possible - quotes, no quotes, and mixed quotes, and I still get mixed results.

```
    #!/bin/bash

CD="/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog"

result=`$CD standard-dropdown --title "Database Tasks" --text "What would you like 
to             
do?"        
--items "Clear Pending Commands" "Clear Verify Signature" "Show Processlist" --button1 "OK"`

if [ "$result" == 0 ]; then
echo "Clearing commands"
elif  [ "$result" == 1 ]; then
echo "Verifying"
elif  [ "$result" == 2 ]; then
echo "Process"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. The dropdown returned multiple returns. I added | tail -1 to my command to get the last line of return.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but for anyone else that runs across this cocoadialog has the ability to quiet the response of clicking okay/no/cancel by using --quiet.